# Matplotlib ValueError: RGBA values should be within 0-1 range

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, rgba

So I tried to make a minimal example of how the error gets thrown but confusingly the minimal example actually works

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)

color_list = [(1.0, 0, 0), (1.0, 0, 0), (1.0, 0, 0), (1.0, 0, 0), (1.0, 0, 0), 
              (0, 1.0, 0), (0, 1.0, 0), (0, 1.0, 0), (0, 1.0, 0), (0, 1.0, 0),
              (0, 0, 1.0), (0, 0, 1.0), (0, 0, 1.0), (0, 0, 1.0), (0, 0, 1.0), 
              (0, 0, 0),   (0, 0, 0),   (0, 0, 0),   (0, 0, 0),   (0, 0, 0)]

for idx in range(0,20):
    ax.plot([0, 10], [10, idx], color=color_list[idx])
```

Here I'm passing RGB tuples from `color_list` to the plot & it works!

[image]

But when I try to do this as part of a much more complicated series of plots using the code below I keep getting `ValueError: RGBA values should be within 0-1 range`

```
alpha = 1.0
col = 0
for g, h in zip(G, H):
        
    bin_count       = 80 
    G_hist          = np.histogram(g, bin_count)
    G_hist_bin      = G_hist[1][-len(G_hist[0]):]
         
    bin_count      = int(1.0 + 3.322 * np.log2(len(h)))
    M_hist         = np.histogram(h, bin_count)
    M_hist_bin     = M_hist[1][-len(M_hist[0]):]
    
    
    ax_1.plot(G_hist_bin, G_hist[0], color = color_list[col],  lw = 1.0, alpha = alpha)
    ax_2.plot(M_hist_bin, M_hist[0],  lw = 1.0, alpha = alpha)
    

    print(col, bin_count)
    col += 1
    alpha -= 0.1
```

So why does this work in the first example but not in the second?

Comment: Maybe some typo in `color_list` so that it contains one bad value? Or alpha is getting smaller than 0?   By the way, a bit more "pythonic" would be to write `for col, (g, h) in enumerate(zip(G, H))`. Or `for col, (g, h, alpha) in enumerate(zip(G, H, np.linspace(1, 0.2, len(G))))`

Comment: @JohanC it was the `alpha` value going negative, good catch

Comment: That's why the `linspace` for `alpha` seems a more flexible approach.